# Publish On Premises Project Server 2013 web services to cloud Power BI

Tags: powerbi, azure-api-management, ms-project-server-2013

We would like to host Power BI reports in cloud, showing reports based on data in our on Premises Project Server 2013.
The data sources we use are

1. /PWA/_api/ProjectData/
2. /PWA/_api/ProjectData/Projects

Since we have a hybrid network, can I publish these APIs with API Management Gateway (so the reports hosted in cloud can refresh data automatically)? How?

Or is there a better way?

Kind regards,
AllWorkNoPlay

Answer (score 0):

Found out we had to set up Power BI Enterprise Gateway, which is an easy and convenient solution.